# Adding group notations outside of the plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add notations for groups outside of ggplot like illustrated in the picture below. I have tried with facet_grid but problems arise when it breaks plots apart from each other so it will not be aligned with the plot that is coming next to it

[image: Example of the desired output]

Code to generate the plot:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=biomarkers) %>%
  left_join(., gene_pct_df, by=c("name" = "biomarkers")) %>%
  mutate(bio_factor = as.numeric(factor(biomarker_groups))) %>% 
  mutate(color_scheme = case_when(
    value == "CC" & bio_factor == 1 ~ "a",
    value == "CC" & bio_factor == 2 ~ "b",
    value == "CC" & bio_factor == 3 ~ "c",
    TRUE ~ "d")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=reorder(name, bio_factor))) +
  geom_raster(aes(x=factor(patient), fill=color_scheme,
                  alpha=color_scheme),
              show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(aes(x=factor(patient), label=value), size=3,
            show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#00BA38" ,"#619CFF", "white"),
                    labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.01),
                     labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d")) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))
```

Example data to test the function:

```
n_pat <- 15
patient <- 1:n_pat
treatment <- sample(c("Drug A", "Drug B"), n_pat, replace=TRUE)
change <- rnorm(n_pat, 0, 20)
biomarkers <- c("T790M","Ex19del","L959R","Ex20Ins","MET","ERBB2","EGFR",
                "EGFR2","PIK3CA","KRAS","CDKN2","RB1","ALK","KIT","MET2",
                "Other")
genes <- matrix(sample(x=c("CC", "AA", "AC"), replace=TRUE, size=n_pat * length(biomarkers)), nrow=n_pat, ncol=length(biomarkers))
biomarker_groups <- c(rep("Baseline", 4), rep("SCNA", 3), rep("SNV", 9))
df <- data.frame(patient, treatment, change, genes)
df <- data.frame(patient, treatment, change, genes)
colnames(df) <- c("patient", "treatment", "change", biomarkers)

genes_df <- df %>%
  select(biomarkers)

pcts <- colSums(genes_df == "CC") / length(df)

gene_pct_df <- data.frame(pcts, biomarker_groups, biomarkers)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `facet_wrap` with `free_y` for both `scale` and `space`, then adjust the panel spacing in `theme()`:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=biomarkers) %>%
  left_join(., gene_pct_df, by=c("name" = "biomarkers")) %>%
  mutate(bio_factor = as.numeric(factor(biomarker_groups))) %>% 
  mutate(color_scheme = case_when(
    value == "CC" & bio_factor == 1 ~ "a",
    value == "CC" & bio_factor == 2 ~ "b",
    value == "CC" & bio_factor == 3 ~ "c",
    TRUE ~ "d")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=reorder(name, bio_factor))) +
  geom_raster(aes(x=factor(patient), fill=color_scheme,
                  alpha=color_scheme),
              show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(aes(x=factor(patient), label=value), size=3,
            show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#00BA38" ,"#619CFF", "white"),
                    labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.01),
                     labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d")) +
  facet_grid(biomarker_groups ~.,
  switch="y",scales="free_y",space = "free_y") + 

  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.y=unit(0,"lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))
```

[image]